# check duplicated data from selected data

Tags: php

Hello i'm going to check duplicated data from selected data but my code is not working properly

the my code is:

```
$cs="0";
$location=array();
$check=array(); $check[0]="";
while ($db_field = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {    
     for ($z=0; $z<=$cs;$z++){
        if($check[$z]==$db_field['location']) { 
          //*in here going to check same or not
        } 
        else {                            
          //*if not same $location_c[$cs] will get
          $location_c[$cs]= $db_field['location'];
          $check[$cs]= $db_field['location'];
        }
    }
    $cs++;
}
```

this code prints all data not checking duplicated data.

Comment: Please indent your code correctly to improve legibility. It will help people more easily answer your questions and potentially see syntax errors and control flow. Also you are setting `$cs` to a string, then comparing it to an int in the for loop is there a a reason for this?

Comment: Have you tried to debug it?  Please see the [FAQs](http://stackoverflow.com/faq).

Comment: $cs will increase by one if not duplicated. it will show not duplicated data's count

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should use `in_array()` to avoid duplication, I've also removed unnecessary things :

```
$location=array();
while ($db_field = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    if(!in_array($db_field['location'], $location_c)) {
        $location_c[] = $db_field['location'];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

assuming the duplicate is the location field

```
$cs="0";
$location=array();
$check=array(); 
while ($db_field = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {    
     for ($z=0; $z<=$cs;$z++){

        if (in_array($db_field['location'], $check)) continue;
        $check[]=$db_field['location'];

        $location_c[$cs]= $db_field['location'];

    }
    $cs++;
}
```

but can't you avoid duplicates with your SQL query?

Answer (score 0):

The first issue you have is in your for statement: `for ($z=0; $z<=$cs;$z++)`. There is no need for this. You should use [in_array()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php) in order to determine, if what your looking for has been set. Also, there is no need to use incremental values for your key. If you use `[]` there is no overhead, and will automatically use number keys.

Lastly, it appears that there is no reason to use a `$check` array at all. You can go straight to `$location_c`. This cuts down a lot of code:

```
$location_c = array();
while ($db_field = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    if(!in_array($db_field['location'],$location_c)){
        $location_c[]= $db_field['location'];
    }
}
```